# Pandas Styler Subset column by values

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-styles

I'm using the following to color the cells in a dataframe:

```
import seaborn as sns

cm1 = sns.diverging_palette(h_pos=130, h_neg=10, s=99, l=55, n=99, as_cmap=True)

df_s = (df.style
    .background_gradient(cmap=cm1, subset=['col1']))
```

This successfully applies the background gradient to the values in `col1`

However, I'd like to something like the following:

```
df_s = (df.style
    .background_gradient(cmap=cm1, subset=['col1'] < x))
```

Which does not work

The idea is to only apply the gradient to values in `col1` which are less than `x`, and display the full dataframe where `col1 >= x` is un-colored.

Seems like there should be an easy way to do this but I can't seem to get the argument into the right format for `subset`.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `pd.IndexSlice`:

```
import seaborn as sns

cm1 = sns.diverging_palette(h_pos=130, h_neg=10, s=99, l=55, n=99, as_cmap=True)
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,(5,5)), columns=[*'ABCDE'])
df.style.background_gradient(cmap=cm1, subset=pd.IndexSlice[df['C']<50, 'C'])
```

Output:

[image]